# Counting performance issue

Tags: performance, linq, count

The class Group is like the following:

```
class Group {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Members { get; set; }

    public dynamic AsJson() {
        return new
        {
            groupId = this.GroupId,
            name = this.Name,
            membersCount = this.Members.Count // issue!
        };
    }
}
```

I have a view where all groups are listed, like follows:

```
Group name      Members
 Bleh             15
 Zort             40
 Narf             12
```

This list is retrieved with an AJAX call which returns a JSON. The action has code like the following:

```
            groups = from g in (db.Groups where ... orderby g.Name).ToList()
                     select g.AsJson();
```

The problem is that this list was taking way too long (like 20 seconds).

I changed "this.Members.Count" with a maintained property, that is:

```
class Group {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Members { get; set; }
    public int MembersCount { get; set; }  // added

    public dynamic AsJson() {
        return new
        {
            groupId = this.GroupId,
            name = this.Name,
            membersCount = this.MembersCount // changed
        };
    }
}
```

And it started to work fine (1-2 secs to generate the list)

**Is there a better way to achieve this?** I'm starting to have problems maintaining the property MembersCount, because Members are added and removed in several parts of the code

Comment: Looks like you should eagerly load `Members` in your LINQ query. I suspect that during serialization, for each `Group` a query is fired to lazy load its `Members`. Is this linq-to-sql?

Comment: I updated the code. It is a mixture of linq to entities and linq to objects

Comment: @GertArnold how would you eagerly load Members in the LINQ query? given the changes I did

Comment: `dbGroups.Include(g => g.Members)`.